# LED in series is not working in Proteus simulation

Tags: led, series, proteus

When I run the Proteus project, all the red LEDs should turn on, but none turn on. You can see that the RA0 is on, and the LEDs series is connected ok.  Am I doing something wrong?

The complete idea is turn and of the PIC's ports, but when I make work the first pin, others would be the same.

[image]

Comment: You have four LEDs in series on each string. With green you'll need at least 8 V to turn them on. What is your Vdd?

Answer (score 5):

It may be because the voltage is too low. Red LED have a forward voltage of at least 1.7 V. So to power 4 LED in series you need at least $$4\cdot 1.7 V = 6.8 V$$
So if the simulator takes forward voltage into account (real diode models, not ideal diodes) and if the output voltage of the PIC is 5 V or even 3.3 V, this will not work.

To make it work, try connecting them in parallel instead of in series. Please note that microcontrollers have some limitations on output current (output pin is not supposed to provide any significant power). One diode is OK, but for multiple diodes in parallel consider switching them using a transistor.